# Consider an entire function $f$ such that $|Re f(z)|\ge |Im f(z)|, \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|\ge M$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Consider an entire function $f$ such that $|Re f(z)|\ge |Im f(z)|,
>  \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|\ge M\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

My attempt:

The inequality has a geometric interpretation: For all points $z$ outside of $B(0,M)$ we can only reach points for which the real part is greater than or equal to the imaginary part. Select $w=a+bi$ with $a>M$ and $b>2a$, then the disk $B(w,M/2)$ is not reached by $f$, which implies that $f$ is constant.

Is this a good approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work.

Comment: How do you jump from the fact that a certain disk doesn't intersect the range of $f$ to the fact that $f$ is constant?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using some "big" theorem to conclude, such as the Picard theorems. (This is the same objection José made). This result should be proven elementarily, in my opinion.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Suppose $f$ is not constant (or else the proof is trivial). The range of a nonconstant, entire function is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The hint for this question was to use the fact that $f$ doesn't reach a certain disk. Is there an elementary approach?

Comment: Hint: if $f$ has no values in a disk $B(a,r)$, then $1/(a-f(z))$ is a bounded entire function.  You need to choose $a$ and $r$ which works for $z$ with $|z|<M$ as well as $|z|\ge M$.

Comment: @Zachary: I was thinking at something along the lines of Robert Israel's hint, which is perfectly elementary. Great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete. You did *not* prove that there is an open disk that doesn't intersect the range of $f$; all that you proved was that there is an open disk that doesn't intersect$$\left\{f(z)\,\middle|\,\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert\geqslant M\right\}.\tag1$$However the range of $f$ is the union of $(1)$ with $f\left(\overline{B(0,M)}\right)$, which is a compact set, and therefore a bounded set. So, since the range of $f$ is a subset of$$\left\{z\in\mathbb Z\,\middle|\,\lvert\operatorname{Re}z\rvert\geqslant\lvert\operatorname{Im}z\rvert\right\}\cup f\left(\overline{B(0,M)}\right)$$which is a closed set but which is *not* the whole complex plane, the range of $f$ cannot possibly be a desnse subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You don't even need dense. Since the above is closed and not the whole plane, there is some $B(a, r)$ that does not intersect the range. Then $g(z)={1 \over f(z)-a}$ is bounded hence constant.

Comment: Sure. That's simpler.